# Split string, ignoring delimiter within quotation marks (python)

Tags: python, csv

I would like to split a string on a comma, but ignore cases when it is within quotation marks:

for example:

```
teststring = '48, "one, two", "2011/11/03"'
teststring.split(",")
['48', ' "one', ' two"', ' "2011/11/03"']
```

and the output I would like is:

```
['48', ' "one, two"', ' "2011/11/03"']
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 31):

The [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) will work if you set options to handle this dialect:

```
>>> import csv
>>> teststring = '48, "one, two", "2011/11/03"'
>>> for line in csv.reader([teststring], skipinitialspace=True):
    print line


['48', 'one, two', '2011/11/03']
```

Comment: +1: nice catch, for this `skipinitialspace`! I tried to understand the `csv` documentation but could not get the OP input to work :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) from the standard library:

```
>>> import csv
>>> testdata = ['48, "one, two", "2011/11/03"']
>>> testcsv = csv.reader(testdata,skipinitialspace=True)
>>> testcsv.next()
['48', 'one, two', '2011/11/03']
```

The one thing to watch out for is that the `csv.reader` objects expect an `iterator` which will return a string each time `next()` is called.  This means that you can't pass a string string straight to a `reader()`, but you can enclose it in a list as above.

You'll have to be careful with the format of your data or tell `csv` how to handle it.  By default **the quotes have to come immediately after the comma** or the `csv` module will interpret the field as beginning with a space rather than being quoted.  You can fix this using [the `skipinitialspace` option](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace).

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem. "one, two" should not be splitted, because the comma is within the quotes, or do I misinterpret something? I tried this here by my own and got the same result as you, reading the doc [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters), I understood that per default it should tread everything inside quotes as one field, per default.

Comment: @Dave webb: Djmac wants `"one, two"` in single variable which not the case in your answer...he requires output as `['48', ' "one, two"', ' "2011/11/03"']`, length = 3 in your case length=4

Comment: @stema - Good point!  I didn't read the output of my code carefully enough.  It turns out the problem is with the sample data.  If a field starts with a space then `csv` assumes the field does too and the `"` is part of the field, i.e. `csv` does not automatically trim each value.  I've fixed the sample data and the code now works.  Thanks for point this out.

Comment: @avasal - as noted above the problem was with the sample data (kind of) rather the code.  Or rather, if you're going to use `csv` you have to be a bit more careful with your data format.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, now its working! Hopefully also for the OP. +1 from me.

Comment: Use the *skipinitialspace* parameter so that the OP doesn't have to change his data to match your code ;-)

Comment: That worked perfectly!Thankyou kindly for your support. . . very much appreciated! (And fast!)

Comment: @RaymondHettinger - thanks; have added the `skipinitialspace` option.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `shlex` module to parse your string.

By default, `shlex.split` will split your string at whitespace characters not enclosed in quotes:

```
>>> shlex.split(teststring)
['48,', 'one, two,', '2011/11/03']
```

This doesn't removes the trailing commas from your string, but it's close to what you need. However, if you customize the parser to consider the comma as a whitespace character, then you'll get the output that you need:

```
>>> parser = shlex.shlex(teststring)
>>> parser.whitespace
' \t\r\n'
>>> parser.whitespace += ','
>>> list(parser)
['48', '"one, two"', '"2011/11/03"']
```

Note: the parser object is used as an iterator to get the tokens one by one. Hence, `list(parser)` iterates over the parser object and returns the string splitted where you need.

Comment: This gets the job done, but isn't as good of a fit as the csv module.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a standard module, you have to install it via pip, but as an option try tssplit:

```
In [5]: from tssplit import tssplit 
In [6]: tssplit('48, "one, two", "2011/11/03"', quote='"', delimiter=',', trim=' ')
Out[6]: ['48', 'one, two', '2011/11/03']
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Python csv library: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: That link isn't enough to solve the problem.  Right out of the box, a csv reader won't correctly parse the OP's test string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import shlex
teststring = '48, "one, two", "2011/11/03"'
output = shlex.split(teststring)
output = [re.sub(r",$","",w) for w in output]
print output
['48', 'one, two', '2011/11/03']
```